# Regular expression with hebrew

Tags: android, regex, hebrew

I have text like:

```
לשלום קוראים לי משהmy test is עלות 39.40, כל מיני data 1.1.2015 ויש גם data 123456 מידע
```

This text have Hebrew and English characters, I need to eliminate all except the 6 digit number (may be 5, this num: 123456).

Can you help me with regular expression for this?

Tried:

```
  String patternS = "[אבגדהוזחטיכךלמםנןסעפףצץקרשתa-fA-F0-9]{5,10}.*";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
```

With no success

Answer (score 0):

To match everything except the number use:

```
\d+(?:[^\d]\d+)+|[\p{L}\p{M}\p{Z}\p{P}\p{S}\p{C}]+

String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("\\d+(?:[^\\d]\\d+)+|[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{Z}\\p{P}\\p{S}\\p{C}]+", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you every 6 didgit combination in your string.

`(\d{6,6})`

We can't give you a more detailled regex since we do now know the pattern of those strings.
In case there is always the "data " prefix you can also use this to make the pattern more accurate:

`data (\d{6,6})`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
String patternS = "(\d{5,6})";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternS);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(yourText);
int number = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
```

where `yourText` is the Hebrew/English text you want to match.

Answer (score 0):

This would work for this specific example.

```
String s = " לשלום קוראים לי מש my test is עלות 39.40, כל מיני data 1.1.2015 ויש גם data 123456 מידע1234";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".*\\b(\\d{5,6})\\b.*", "$1"));
```